# Re-assembling polygons after running CGAL's split_graph_into_polylines()

Tags: c++, boost, cgal, polyline, simplification

In order to simplify multipolygons in CGAL, including their shared boundaries, I followed [the instructions as answered in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779837/is-there-any-way-to-get-cgals-polyline-simplification-to-work-for-inner-shared/64800095#64800095).

So, I start out with polygons, but iterate through the polygons and add their coordinates to a `boost::adjacency_list` graph of edges. Then, I run `CGAL::split_graph_into_polylines()` on the graph. Then, I simplify the polylines (`Polyline_2`) by creating a CT object, store the polylines in there, then run CGAL::simplify(). After the simplification, however, how would I go about converting the resulting polylines to polygons (`Polygon_2`)? Ultimately, I would like to convert these simplified polylines to polygons so that I can export them as GeoJSON files.

Thank you!